# Gradle: Can not find package in build

Tags: build, jar, project, package, gradle

I'm just new to Gradle, and I have a small problem with it. I'm trying to build two projects (called 'infrastructure' and 'domain'), where domain has some imports from infrastructure.

When I try to build both projects, Gradle can't compile my domain project, because he can't find a package from infrastructure.

This is my build.gradle:

```
subprojects{
    apply plugin: 'java'

    springversion = '3.0.4.RELEASE'
    hibernateversion = '3.4.0.GA'
    jsfversion = '2.0.3'
    projectid = 'com.companyName.projectName'
    projectversion = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

    repositories {
        mavenRepo urls: 'file:///C:/companyName/m2repo'
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile group: 'commons-configuration', name: 'commons-configuration', version: '1.6'
        compile group: 'sample.plugin', name: 'hsqldb-maven-plugin', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.8.2'
        testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '1.8.0'
        testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: springversion

        compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: springversion
        compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: springversion 
        compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: springversion 
        compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-annotations', version: hibernateversion 
        compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: hibernateversion
        compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'ejb3-persistence', version: '1.0.2.GA' 
        compile group: 'javax.enterprise', name: 'cdi-api', version: '1.0-CR1'
        compile group: 'com.sun.faces', name: 'jsf-api', version: jsfversion
        compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.5'
        runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.5.6'
        runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-jdk14', version: '1.5.6'
        runtime group: 'org.hsqldb', name: 'hsqldb', version: '1.8.0.10'
        runtime group: 'commons-dbcp', name: 'commons-dbcp', version: '1.2.2'
        runtime group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.6.2'
    }

}

project (':infrastructure'){
    task intTestJar(type: Jar) {
        from sourceSets.main.classes
        from sourceSets.test.classes
    }
}

project(':domain'){
    compileJava.dependsOn (':infrastructure:intTestJar')        
}
```

In my settings.gradle, I've declared this:

```
include 'infrastructure', 'domain'
```

Both projects should be built to a .jar file.

When try to build the projects, this error is shown when he is running domain:compileTestJava

```
package com.companyName.projectName.test does not exist
```

This package refers to my infrastructure project. In eclipse it works, but I can't build it with gradle.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Walle

Comment: I've changed `project(':domain')...` to `project(':domain'){ compileJava.dependsOn (':infrastructure:build') }`, so he builds the infrastructure project before he starts compiling the domain project. But he still can't find the package...

Comment: Strange... I don't see anything wrong. BTW, you don't need to add the infrastructure project as a dependency of the testCompile scope; testCompile inherits from compile.

Comment: Are you trying to use infrastructure's test classes? If yes, that is the problem. When you depend on infrastructure, gradle only puts infrastructure's classes and not its test classes to the classpath. Let me know if this is the case and I'll write up an answer.

Comment: That is indeed the problem. I have some basic testclasses in the infrastructure testpackage, and the tests from domain inherit from them. He cant find those testclasses, and that's why he can't compile.

Comment: Edited my first post. I've changed some stuff, but it still gives the same error.

Comment: You'll probably have to define a `testCompile` dependency to the `infrastructure` module: `project(':domain') { dependencies { testCompile project(':infrastructure') } }`.

Comment: I already tried that, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
subprojects{
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    springversion = '3.0.4.RELEASE'
    hibernateversion = '3.4.0.GA'
    jsfversion = '2.0.3'
    projectid = 'com.companyName.projectName'
    projectversion = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

    repositories {
        mavenRepo urls: 'file:///C:/companyName/m2repo'
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile group: 'commons-configuration', name: 'commons-configuration', version: '1.6'
        compile group: 'sample.plugin', name: 'hsqldb-maven-plugin', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.8.2'
        testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name:    'mockito-core', version: '1.8.0'
        testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: springversion

        compile group: projectid, name: 'infrastructure', version: projectversion
        compile group: projectid, name: 'domain', version: projectversion
        compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: springversion
        compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: springversion 
        compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: springversion 
        compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-annotations', version: hibernateversion 
        compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: hibernateversion
        compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'ejb3-persistence', version: '1.0.2.GA' 
        compile group: 'javax.enterprise', name: 'cdi-api', version: '1.0-CR1'
        compile group: 'com.sun.faces', name: 'jsf-api', version: jsfversion
        compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.5'
        runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.5.6'
        runtime group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-jdk14', version: '1.5.6'
        runtime group: 'org.hsqldb', name: 'hsqldb', version: '1.8.0.10'
        runtime group: 'commons-dbcp', name: 'commons-dbcp', version: '1.2.2'
        runtime group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.6.2'
    }
    test{
        maxParallelForks=2
    }
}

project(':infrastructure'){
    task infrastructureTestJar(type: Jar) {
        from sourceSets.main.classes
        from sourceSets.test.classes
    }
    infrastructureTestJar.dependsOn(jar) 
}

project(':domain'){
    compileJava.dependsOn(':infrastructure:build')
    dependencies{
        compile files('../infrastructure/build/libs/infrastructure.jar')
    }
    task domainTestJar(type: Jar) {
        from sourceSets.main.classes
        from sourceSets.test.classes
    }
    domainTestJar.dependsOn(jar)
}
```

Comment: Can you summarize the salient changes you made in your build.gradle file?